# 5 domain UCC SSL not working for the domain url with www

Tags: ssl, windows, csr

I have a AWS lightsail server in which I created 5 domains in it using Plesk web admin. I am having single IP for all the domains since the lightsail server only provides 1 IP for single server. I am using 5 domains UCC SAN SSL from godaddy for my 5 domains. When generating/re-keying the SSL I provide the CSR generated in the Plesk for single domain, since godaddy has only one option to update CSR in SSL and I gave other 4 domains as Alt-name. While giving the Alt-name I gave the domain name in the format www.domain.tld .

After downloading and installing the SSL I found out that the SSL is not working for the url with www but works perfectly for the url without www. For the domain whose CSR is supplied is working perfectly for the url with and without www. Is there any way that I can make the SSL work for the other 4 domains with www?

Comment: I doubt that these information are sufficient to help with your problem since it is not known what exactly the content of the certificate is you've got. But in general - if a domain is not included in a certificate you cannot somehow make it work with the existing certificate.

Comment: "if a domain is not included in a certificate ...." -- I can rekey the certificate

Comment: rekeying does not change the domains a certificate is issued for. It changes the key only.

Comment: My SSL is of 5 domain so the certificate include all 5 domain in it. but my problem is SSL not working for the url with www

Comment: Again, the certificate must contain the full and complete names of all domains you use. It is still unknown what your certificate exactly contains and what name you are using in the URL. Note that to get `https://example.com` working the certificate must contain `example.com` and `www.example.com` is not sufficient.

Comment: What else is required if i need to to get the https://www.example.com and https://www.example2.com in the single certificate with www?

Comment: Why on earth are you still buying SSL certificates? Just do Let's Encrypt.

Comment: Any modern web browsers (especially Chrome) would require SAN extension to contain all your 5 domains. Also the description of "SSL is not working" is useless. What exactly is the problem?